# General Approach in Zen-Theming: 3 different fixed-width layouts based on viewport-size

Tags: theming

I am building a zen-subtheme which should have 3 breakpoints depending on viewport-size, but none of the layouts has sidebars, there is a small horizontal navigation for all layouts.
By default, Zen provides a responsive-sidebars.scss and fixed-width.scss - since i need media-queries on one hand but no fluid sidebars etc. on the other hand, i don't know, what's the best way to go.

Comment: try omega theme.

Comment: You could also remove all sidebar references in your subtheme and customize it for your needs... it's all plug and play :)

Comment: thanks for your hints! i think i'll give omega-theme a try.

Answer (score 1):

Zen 5 has mobile/responsive built-in, and it works really well. I found the conversion from Zen 3 fixed to Zen 5-Responsive fairly easy, and I went with the dev version (Jan 2013). As suggested, you could take out all the sidebars, but they don't really get in the way.

I had to spend some time learning responsive images, in particular responsive background images.